# uBlock - block all network queries that contain certain text in their bodies

Tags: ublock-origin, ublock

Some site sends me a json `{..., "category": "Ads",...}`. Can I block all requests and responses containing `"category": "Ads"`?

I'm looking for something like `||example.com$body-has-text("category": "Ads")`

Comment: If you can read response body, then the request has already been sent.

Comment: Okay, is it possible to block a response that has a `"category": "Ads"`?

Comment: From a practical point of view, no.  You can search for these phrases with a packet sniffer (Comm View), find the source and block the source in your firewall. Seems like a lot of work for little payback.

Comment: You will need to identify these *requests* by their parameters, then you can add rules to uBlock.

Comment: @harrymc, what parameters are you talking about? There aren't any URL parameters. The URL is legit. Response headers also have no distinctive features.

Comment: I'm talking about URL like `https://domain?parameters`. You can see that through the developer tools of the browser, or apps like Fiddler & Wireshark.

Comment: Unfortunately, there aren't any URL parameters in the URL I'd like to block.